# React 'removeChild ' on 'Node' for youtube iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, youtube-api

[Codesandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/youtube-player-2-d5li0?file=/src/index.tsx)

I have a component that renders a div and on mount inserts a youtube iframe to the div. I want to be able to toggle this component to show and hide it. However, whenever I 'hide' the component (unmount it), I get the following error message:

> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.

How can I unmount this component? Thanks.

**index.tsx:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

declare global {
  interface Window {
    YT: any;
    onYouTubeIframeAPIReady: Function;
  }
}

const YoutubePlayer: React.FC = () => {
  const videoFrameId = "youtube-player-1";
  const onPlayerReady = (event: { [key: string]: any }): void => {
    event.target.playVideo();
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const loadVideo = (): void => {
      new window.YT.Player(videoFrameId, {
        videoId: "5qap5aO4i9A",
        events: {
          onReady: onPlayerReady
        }
      });
    };

    // If not, load the script asynchronously
    if (!window.YT) {
      const tag = document.createElement("script");
      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";

      // onYouTubeIframeAPIReady will load the video after the script is loaded
      window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = loadVideo;

      const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
    } else {
      // If script is already there, load the video directly
      loadVideo();
    }
  }, []);

  return <div id={videoFrameId} />;
};

export default YoutubePlayer;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setShow(prevState => !prevState)}>
        {show ? "Hide Player" : "Show Player"}
      </button>
      {show && <YoutubePlayer />}
    </>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: This problem comes from the fact that YT replaces your <div id={videoFrameId} /> node with its own iframe html tag. This messes up react a bit as root node of component is important. If you wrap it in something before returning it from render you should have no problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be a pretty easy fix. Give the player a defined parent element.

```
{show && <div><YoutubePlayer /></div>}
```

instead of

```
{show && <YoutubePlayer />}
```

The removeChild call should then not fail.

---

EDIT: Or even better, do it inside so the caller does not need to do the wrapping.

```
return <div><div id={videoFrameId} /></div>;
```

in place of

```
return <div id={videoFrameId} />;
```